# InfluxdB Flux Query group by substring

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I search a way to group by substring/regex of a column:

I search in the documentation https://docs.influxdata.com/ without success.

The column "proc" is composed as follow:

```
    CPU-010.CORE010-00
    CPU-010.CORE010-01
    CPU-010.CORE010-02
    CPU-010.CORE010-03
    CPU-010.CORE010-04
    CPU-010.CORE010-05
    ...
    CPU-020.CORE020-00
    CPU-020.CORE020-01
    CPU-020.CORE020-02
    CPU-020.CORE020-03
    CPU-020.CORE020-04
    ...
    CPU-110.CORE110-00
    CPU-110.CORE110-01
    CPU-110.CORE110-02
    CPU-110.CORE110-03
    CPU-110.CORE110-04
    ...
    CPU-120.CORE120-00
    CPU-120.CORE120-01
    CPU-120.CORE120-02
    CPU-120.CORE120-03
    etc..
```

The csv imported is composed as follow:

```
#datatype measurement,tag,tag,double,dateTime:number
Processors,srv,proc,usage,time
Processors,srv1,CPU-010.CORE010-00,52,1671231960
Processors,srv1,CPU-010.CORE010-00,50,1671232020
Processors,srv1,CPU-010.CORE010-00,49,1671232080
Processors,srv1,CPU-010.CORE010-00,50,1671232140
Processors,srv1,CPU-010.CORE010-00,48,1671232200
Processors,srv1,CPU-010.CORE010-00,53,1671232260
...
Processors,srv1,CPU-020.CORE020-00,52,1671231960
Processors,srv1,CPU-020.CORE020-00,50,1671232020
Processors,srv1,CPU-020.CORE020-00,49,1671232080
Processors,srv1,CPU-020.CORE020-00,50,1671232140
Processors,srv1,CPU-020.CORE020-00,48,1671232200
Processors,srv1,CPU-020.CORE020-00,53,1671232260
...
```

I tried with this query without success:

```
from(bucket: v.bucket)
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "Processors" and proc.p =~ /(CPU-[09].*)[.].*/)
  |> group(columns: ["proc"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean)
```

I tried to group as follow:

```
CPU-010
CPU-020
CPU-110
CPU-120
Etc..
```

Many thank for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to group by the prefix of the column names, you could try following:

1. create a new column based on the prefix
2. group by the new column

Sample code is as follows:

```
from(bucket: v.bucket)
   |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
   |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "Processors")
   |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with newProc: strings.substring(v: r._value, start: 0, end: 7)}))
   |> group(columns: ["newProc"])
   |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean)
```

Notice: **|> aggregateWindow(column: "_value", every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean)** ou can specify the column this way. Before trying this, try comment out this line to see the results before the aggregation, especially the column names.

See more details for [map](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/map/#add-new-columns-and-preserve-existing-columns) function and [substring](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/strings/substring/#return-part-of-a-string-based-on-character-index) function and [aggregateWindow](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/aggregatewindow/#specify-parameters-of-the-aggregate-function) function.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I tried with your code, but i got an error:  invalid: runtime error @7:6-7:90: map: type conflict: string != float. I need to convert the value of each CPU-* in float?

Comment: oops, that's because the aggregateWindow function works on some column and that column was used to calculate the mean but its values are string type. Could you try print out the values first and then specify the column explicitly.

Comment: I'm updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: I edited and added the csv used about theses datas. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct syntax with your sample code:

```
import "strings"

from(bucket: v.bucket)
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Processors")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "usage")
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with newProc: strings.substring(v: r.proc, start: 0, end: 7)}))
|> group(columns: ["newProc"])
|> aggregateWindow(column: "_value", every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean) 
|> yield(name: "mean")
```

Many thanks for your help.